# How to make USB camera work in Open CV in C #?

Tags: c#, opencv

```
videoCapture = highgui.CvCreateCameraCapture(0);
```

This is the code that I am using to get the camera capture . Though its working for the laptop webcam , it is not working for a camera connected from **USB** .

This is the [C# wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Intel_OpenCV.aspx) I am using..

Answer (score 1):

I recently had difficulties getting OpenCV to read from anything beyond the 'first' webcam, just couldn't get it to work (though I did **not** debug the OpenCV libraries themselves, I was looking for a quick solution).  I ended up using DirectShow capture which did work capturing video from both sources.  You might want to try using [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) to get the video capture to work on your external webcam.